# Entity Framework - Updating List of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

I am working on a project that requires me to save data in a database. To cut time and effort, I used EF Code First implementation. The project is a movie booking system, and I've implemented it the following way:

- Movie class (stores movie information)
- Room class (stores metrics of room (number of rows and columns of chairs), represents a room)
- Show class (stores a movie show - contains reference to the Movie and Room objects, also creates a List of Seats based on the Room, and a list of Bookings. Contains two DateTime for the beginning and the end of the show)
- Booking class (stores information about a booking - phone number of the person, and a list of Tickets)
- Ticket class (stores chair row and column reference, price)

So basically, at the end, I have a Show object, that has a List of Seats, and a List of Bookings, where each Booking has a list of Tickets. But no matter how I try, I cannot make Entity Framework update these lists simply - I always have to delete the existing entries, then insert the new Show recursively.

Is there any simple solution that instructs Entity Framework that it should check for changes in the Lists too during update? Or do I have to write a recursive update for all the lists stored?

Comment: Can you show us some code (e.g. models, save function)?

Comment: Here it is: https://gist.github.com/fonix232/7987687 It is done using the DbContext.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(new), as this was the closest I could get to proper object update.

Comment: I got your problem, but unfortunately I never use this approach (the `cx.Entry(orig).CurrentValues.SetValues(obj);` function) for updating entities. When I need to make changes in an entity or a list I always do that manually (clearing the list and adding again), I'm curious to find out how that can be improved.

Comment: Well obviously a comparison-based update would be preferred (get stored list, compare elements by key, update existing, add new), but right now it is not solved in any way. Problem is that simply emptying the list won't clear up the database of the stored list - it will add new entries of the referred Bookings and Tickets, and they will get new IDs, etc. It could be solved by directly storing the tickets and bookings (not just referring to them), but that would screw up my entire system I've built up.

Comment: I also tried the Attach and Item.State solution, but that way it never got saved, no matter what was updated (a simple property, e.g. String, or a List).